# Self Hosted WCF communication fails to DB

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, communication, self-hosting

I have an application using WCF self-hosted services (connecting to an MSMQ).  Using Entity Framework, I am trying to read some data from a database on another server, and get the following error.  I'm not sure what the issue is here... though there is a firewall between the app and DB servers.  We did open up SQL ports communication.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
>   Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction
>   manager was unable to push the transaction to the destination
>   transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes
>   are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the
>   MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their
>   NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled
>   for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8004D02A)

What causes this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442210/distributed-transaction-coordinator-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open

Comment: Looks like you're created a distributed transaction by opening up multiple connections. One to MSMQ and one to EF. If you can't prevent the multiple connections configure the MSDTC service for this to work...

Comment: What specifically would I configure?  You mean open firewall, or change MSDTC settings?

Comment: And would you have to configure on client or server, or both?